# Google Drive API error in cron job

Tags: php, curl, ssl, google-drive-api

I have a cron job in cpanel that connects to google drive to backup the website files and database regularly to google drive account. I simplified the file to spot the problem:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

require_once 'google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client>setClientId('xxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxx');
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$accessToken = '{ "access_token" : "xxx", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600, 
"refresh_token" : "1/xxx" }';
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$files = $service->files->listFiles();

print($files);

 ?>
```

I authenticated and got the refresh token and the access token and put them in the variable `$accessToken`. The script works when run from browser but when i set it as a cron job I get the following errors:

```
[13-Jul-2013 13:41:02 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 
'Google_IOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) error setting certificate verify     
locations:
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
' in /home/xxxxxx/backup/google-api-php-client/io/Google_CurlIO.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxxx/backup/google-api-php-client/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(270):    
Google_CurlIO->makeRequest(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 /home/xxxxxx/backup/google-api-php-client/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(248): 
Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
#2 /home/xxxxxx/backup/google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php(315): 
Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/xxxxxx...')
#3 /home/xxxxxx/backup/index.php(20): Google_Client-   
>refreshToken('1/xxxxxx...')
#4 {main}
thrown in /home/xxxxxx/backup/google-api-php-client/io/Google_CurlIO.php on line   
128
```

Comment: Different cUrl settings on cron? It is not able to validate the certificate for SSL.

Comment: so how to interpret that or any fix?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and changed the permissions but still could not get it to work. I then found this solution

In ‘google-api-php-client\src\io\’ folder, open ‘apiCurlIO.php’
Replace
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

on this [link](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-google-account-oauth_231.html) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

cUrl cant write the certificate to its destination.

```
$ chmod 755 /etc/pki/tls/certs
```

Or explicitly set a new destination for certificates that your use have write permissions.

Comment: in my ftp i have found that the /etc/ folder doesn't have this path at all..don't know why...i assume that my hosting doesn't support ssl certificates as i don't have this option in my cpanel

Answer (score 0):

In long running Google Drive API jobs I've also seen scripts crash with this error because they're unable to open new files.